# Joining Polylines in AutoCAD with C#

Tags: c#, autocad

I am trying to select all polylines of a specific layer and then join them with the normal autocad _JOIN command. For some reason i just cant get it to work.

The selectionset is properly found as i could loop through it and change the color of the polyline (just did that for testing purpose)

What am i missing/doing wrong here?

```
        [CommandMethod("JOINPOLY", 
                        CommandFlags.UsePickSet |
                        CommandFlags.Redraw |
                        CommandFlags.Modal)]
    public void SelectAllPolylineByLayer()
    {
        Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;

        using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        { 
            try
            {
                // create the typevalue (criteria what should be selected)
                TypedValue[] tvs = new TypedValue[] {
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Operator), "<and"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.LayerName), "Test unlocked"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Operator), "<or"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Start), "POLYLINE"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Start), "LWPOLYLINE"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Start), "POLYLINE2D"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Start), "POLYLINE3d"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Operator), "or>"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Operator), "and>")
                };

                // create a selectionfilter out of our created typevalue
                SelectionFilter oSf = new SelectionFilter(tvs);
                PromptSelectionResult selRes = ed.SelectAll(oSf);

                // if there is a problemw ith the promtselection stop here
                if (selRes.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
                {
                    ed.WriteMessage("\nError in getting the selectAll");
                    return;
                }

                SelectionSet ss = selRes.Value;

                ed.Command("_JOIN", ss, "");
                tr.Commit();                                       
            }
            //Catch the error and write the errormessage
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                ed.WriteMessage(Convert.ToString(ex));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if anyone still cares about that this was the end result i came up with in the end
i save all entities into a list of a class that has entity, startpoint and endpoint of the polylines saved

then i compare if start and endpoints of the elements in list match and join them with entity.join()

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Gets a layerName and tries to join all polylines on the given layer        
    /// sends back a little log message to display
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="layerName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string JoinPolylineOnLayer(Database db, string layerName)
    {
        Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;                        

        TypedValue[] tvs = null;            

        using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            LayerTable layerTable = (LayerTable)tr.GetObject(db.LayerTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);

            try
            {
                // get layerid of the selected layer
                var layerId = layerTable[layerName];

                // open layer table record with write privileges
                // if the layer is locked return with an error message that the layer cant be deleted
                LayerTableRecord layer = (LayerTableRecord)tr.GetObject(layerId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                if (layer.IsLocked)
                    return "' cannot be merged(locked).";

                // create the typevalue (criteria what should be selected)
                tvs = new TypedValue[] {
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Operator), "<and"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.LayerName), layerName),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Operator), "<or"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Start), "POLYLINE"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Start), "LWPOLYLINE"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Start), "POLYLINE2D"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Start), "POLYLINE3D"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Operator), "or>"),
                                new TypedValue(Convert.ToInt32(DxfCode.Operator), "and>")
                };

                // create a list of the entities
                List<PolylineClass> entities = FillListOfEntities(tvs, tr, ed);

                for (int i = entities.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {                        
                    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // check if start/endpoints are the same
                            // if they are join them and reset the loops and start again
                            if ((entities[i].StartPoint == entities[j].StartPoint) ||
                                (entities[i].StartPoint == entities[j].EndPoint) ||
                                (entities[i].EndPoint == entities[j].StartPoint) ||
                                (entities[i].EndPoint == entities[j].EndPoint))
                            {
                                Entity srcPLine = entities[i].Ent;
                                Entity addPLine = entities[j].Ent;

                                // join both entities
                                srcPLine.UpgradeOpen();
                                srcPLine.JoinEntity(addPLine);

                                // delete the joined entity
                                addPLine.UpgradeOpen();
                                entities.RemoveAt(j);
                                addPLine.Erase();

                                // set new start and end point of the joined polyline
                                entities[i - 1] = new PolylineClass(srcPLine, GetStartPointData(srcPLine), GetEndPointData(srcPLine));

                                // reset i to the start (as it has changed)
                                i = entities.Count; 
                                j = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (System.Exception ex)
                        {
                            ed.WriteMessage("\nError: n{0}", ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                tr.Commit();
                return "' have been joined";
            }
            //Catch the error and write the errormessage
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                return Convert.ToString(ex);
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Function to fill the entities list with a give TypedValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tvs"></param>
    /// <param name="tr"></param>
    /// <param name="ed"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<PolylineClass> FillListOfEntities(TypedValue[] tvs, Transaction tr, Editor ed)
    {
        SelectionFilter oSf = new SelectionFilter(tvs);
        PromptSelectionResult selRes = ed.SelectAll(oSf);

        // if there is a problemw ith the promtselection stop here
        if (selRes.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // declare a list and fill it with all elements from our selectionfilter
        List<PolylineClass> entities = new List<PolylineClass>();

        foreach (ObjectId obj in selRes.Value.GetObjectIds())
        {
            Entity ent = tr.GetObject(obj, OpenMode.ForRead) as Entity;
            entities.Add(new PolylineClass(ent, GetStartPointData(ent), GetEndPointData(ent)));
        }

        return entities;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Function to get the startpoint coordinates of a polyline
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Point3d GetStartPointData(Entity obj)
    {            
        // If a "lightweight" (or optimized) polyline
        Polyline lwp = obj as Polyline;
        if (lwp != null)
        {
            return new Point3d(lwp.GetPoint2dAt(0).X, lwp.GetPoint2dAt(0).Y, lwp.Elevation);
        }
        else
        {
            // If an old-style, 2D polyline
            Polyline2d p2d = obj as Polyline2d;
            if (p2d != null)
            {
                return new Point3d (p2d.StartPoint.X, p2d.StartPoint.Y, p2d.Elevation);
            }
            else
            {
                // If an old-style, 3D polyline
                Polyline3d p3d = obj as Polyline3d;
                if (p3d != null)
                {
                    return p3d.StartPoint;
                }
            }
        }
        return new Point3d(0, 0, 0);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Function to get the endpoint coordinates of a polyline
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Point3d GetEndPointData(Entity obj)
    {
        // If a "lightweight" (or optimized) polyline
        Polyline lwp = obj as Polyline;
        if (lwp != null)
        {
            return new Point3d(lwp.GetPoint2dAt(lwp.NumberOfVertices - 1).X, lwp.GetPoint2dAt(lwp.NumberOfVertices - 1).Y, lwp.Elevation);
        }
        else
        {
            // If an old-style, 2D polyline
            Polyline2d p2d = obj as Polyline2d;
            if (p2d != null)
            {
                return new Point3d(p2d.EndPoint.X, p2d.EndPoint.Y, p2d.Elevation);
            }
            else
            {
                // If an old-style, 3D polyline
                Polyline3d p3d = obj as Polyline3d;
                if (p3d != null)
                {
                   return  p3d.EndPoint;
                }
            }
        }
        return new Point3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the editor command seems to be different from the client join

as workaround i am using the following now:

```
doc.SendStringToExecute("._JOIN\n_p\n\n", true, false, false);
```

i am not 100% happy with it but well, that's what i have to go with for now.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do that (if you are using a version of AutoCAD >= 2013) is to use the `Polyline.JoinEntities` method.

Don't forget to read the doc :

> Polyline.JoinEntities requires the given entities to be **other, unclosed Polyline or Polyline2d, Line, and/or Arc entities, which share common start or end points**.

To handle the 3D polylines, you have to convert them to lines/2D polylines (of course all the entities must be in the same plane).

There is a sample here: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/joining-2d-3d-polylines.html

Comment: that give me a good point to look into
i think i misinterpreted my problem a bit, i dont want to join 3d polylines with 2d. i just want to join all 3d polies with other 3d polies and all 2d with other 2d ones.

Comment: As a side point, have you considered purchasing dedicated routines for this purpose? I know of a website where they have this routine that can be purchased for doing multiple join of 2D and 3D polylines. Might save you re-inventing the wheel.